# Why does tomato not dissolve when I make curry

Tags: tomatoes, curry

when I am cooking curry, I add chopped tomatoes. I cook the tomatoes for 30+ minutes.  In spite of this the tomatoes do not fully dissolve by the end of cooking. There are still whole pieces of tomato that have become cooked but still not become a paste. I have also added water and let the food to simmer, but the tomatoes do not dissolve.

How do I make sure that all tomatoes dissolve into paste when cooking curry?

Comment: Use tomato paste/sauce or blend the tomatoes first? Why would you assume they would dissolve?

Comment: I see people on youtube add tomatoes which dissolve, (must remove the skin). My mother does the same and they always dissolve. What is the magic to this?

Comment: How big are your tomahto pieces?

Comment: well perhaps 1 cm by 1 cm by 1/2 cm. How small should they be?

Comment: Sounds like your curry isn't boiling enough to dissolve the tomatoes, that's all. Is it barely simmering? Is it a lot of curry in a huge pot? Are you adding cold water, bringing the temperature of the curry down?

Comment: if you don't want tomato crunchy (which is almost inevitable if you simply dice it and don't cook the bejeesus out of it), you should blend it.  peel the skin off in either case

Answer (score 4):

If Tomatoes aren't cooking quickly. What i do is heat enough oil to high temp and add finely chopped tomatoes and let them cook in oil. Do not add water. Tomatoes have natural water in it. keep stirring till they break down and dissolve. Let all of its water nearly evaporate. Once oil starts separating from tomatoes that means its done.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, cooking them in oil makes turns them into gravy. Put a lid on the pot and add some salt and let them get cooked in the oil. stirring them here and there to cook them evenly